# Android USB Driver

Tags: android-sdk, android-adb

Купил себе планшет (Samsung ativ smart pc с процессором Intel Atom) на Windows 8. Поставил Eclipse, скачал нужные библиотеки через *Android SDK Manager* в том числе и *Google USB Driver*. При подключении телефона появляется неизвестное устройство SAMSUNG_Android (телефон Samsung GT-9001). Пытался указывать драйвера вручную *sdk\extras\google\usb_driver*, но в ответ получаю что драйвер для устройства не найден.
Попытался установить драйвер от Samsung Kies. Процесс adb.exe висит в системе, но толку от него никакого. Этот же телефон на Windows 7 прекрасно работает.
Может кто-нибудь сталкивался с такой проблемой?

Comment: [Google:samsung android usb driver](https://www.google.ru/search?q=samsung+driver+usb&oq=samsung+driver+&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l3.11287j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#newwindow=1&q=samsung+android+usb+driver&safe=off)

Comment: Не помогло